# Why won't my DataContext use SQL Server Compact Edition 4, rather than trying to use 3.5?

Tags: linq-to-sql, asp.net-mvc-2, sql-server-ce, sql-server-ce-4

I'm playing around with [SQL Server Compact Edition 4 CTP1](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=0d2357ea-324f-46fd-88fc-7364c80e4fdb&displaylang=en) as I'd like to use it as a datastore for a low-traffic web app. When I try to create a `DataContext` with a connection string specifying `System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0` (in order to use LINQ To SQL), I get the following error message:

```
Cannot open '|DataDirectory|\data.sdf'. Provider 'System.Data.SqlServerCe.3.5' not installed.
```

So why is my code not using version 4 of SQL CE?

Back story: I'm using Visual Web Developer Express 2010 for development, but I downloaded the WebMatrix beta and used its designer to create a SQL CE 4 `.sdf` file containing some test data.

Using the `SqlCeConnection/SqlCeCommand/SqlCeDataReader` classes, I've successfully created a basic MVC app which retrieves the test data and displays it. The SQL CE 4 binaries are copied into the app's `bin` folder. In my controller:

```
var connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Main"].ConnectionString;
var tmp = new Dictionary<string, string>();

using(var conn = new SqlCeConnection(connectionString))
{
    conn.Open();

    using (SqlCeDataReader r = new SqlCeCommand("select * from ttest", conn).ExecuteReader())
    {
        while (r.Read())
        {
            tmp.Add(r["id"].ToString(), r["name"].ToString());
        }
    }
}

return View(new TestViewModel { 
    Items = tmp
});
```

The connection string in `Web.config` is as follows:

```
<add name="Main" connectionString="Data Source=|DataDirectory|\data.sdf" providerName="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" />
```

**This works perfectly**, so I know the connection string is correct and that I've set up the binaries properly etc. So I thought I'd try out a bit of LINQ To SQL stuff, which is how I want to build the real app:

```
[Table(Name = "tTest")]
public class TestEntity
{
    [Column(IsPrimaryKey = true, IsDbGenerated = true)]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    [Column]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Repository
{
    private Table<TestEntity> testTable;

    public Repository()
    {
        var connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Main"].ConnectionString;
        var context = new DataContext(connectionString);
        testTable = context.GetTable<TestEntity>();
    }

    public IQueryable<TestEntity> TestEntities
    {
        get { return testTable;  }
    }
}
```

And then in the controller (`db` being a `Repository` constructed in the controller constructor):

```
var tmp = db.TestEntities.ToDictionary(x => x.ID.ToString(), x => x.Name);

return View(new TestViewModel { 
    Items = tmp
});
```

But when I view the page using this code, I get the aforementioned error:

```
Cannot open '|DataDirectory|\data.sdf'. Provider 'System.Data.SqlServerCe.3.5' not installed.
```

How can I force my app to use the correct version? Can anyone help?

Comment: I am also trying to do the same, but result is bit different, error message is that ASP.NET doesn't support SQLCE.

Though, I am using SQLCE 4.0 RTM.

If you are successful pl. let me know.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

LINQ to SQL is not supported by SQL Server Compact 4.0, only Entity Framework / LINQ to Entities. But if you pass a version 4 SqlCeConnection to the DataContext constructor, it will actually work!

Comment: Ok, thanks - [your article](http://erikej.blogspot.com/2010/11/using-entity-framework-with-sql-server.html) was very helpful too. Am I right in thinking that LINQ to SQL was supported by SQL CE 3.5 though? And if so, why did they remove the support?

Comment: Thanks! Yes, LINQ to SQL was supported by SQL CE 3.5. Priorities and support for new features only available in EF (model first / code fist), and better support for EF with ASP.NET, OData, Dynamic Data etc.

Comment: And here's the supporting link saying SQL CE 4 doesn't work with Linq to SQL: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlservercompact/archive/2011/01/12/microsoft-sql-server-compact-4-0-is-available-for-download.aspx